# Finding the transition probability matrix

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

$$P(ξ_i = k) = 1/m$$
for $$k = 1, 2, . . . , m.$$

Explain why $(X_n)_{n≥0}$is a Markov chain.

Write down the state space and the transition probability matrix of $(X_n)_{n≥0}$.

Comment: First: What are the states of the Markov chain?

Comment: Are the states just 1,2,...,m?

Comment: What do $1, 2, \ldots, m$ mean here? That is, $1, 2, \ldots m$ _what_?

Comment: the lifetimes of the batteries?

Comment: Right---so, to determine the transition matrix, we just need to determine for each number of hours of battery life how many hours of life the battery in its slot will have (and with what probability) an hour later.

Comment: That's where I get a little confused. Isn't it possible to get any lifetime on 1,..,m which is uniformly distributed?

Comment: I'll write up a short answer describing this in a little detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the states of the Markov chain are the possible remaining lifetimes of the battery in hours, namely, $1, 2, \ldots, m$.

As usual, the entries $T_{ij}$ of the transition matrix are the probability that a system in state $j$ will transition during a given iteration into state $i$. (If you use the reverse convention, in which case state vectors are row vectors and not column vectors, just take the transpose of all of the matrix objects.)

- If at some time the state battery has $k > 1$ hours of life left, then the behavior is deterministic: The battery is not replaced, in which case when the system iterates, the battery will have $k - 1$ hours left. Thus, for $k > 1$, $T_{k - 1, k} = 1$ and $T_{ik} = 0$ for $i \neq k - 1$.
- On the other hand, if the remaining battery life is $1$ hour, then when the system iterates, the battery is replaced with a new battery of uniformly distributed lifetime, i.e., for all $k = 1, \ldots, m$ the length of the battery's life has a probability $\frac{1}{m}$ of being $k$ hours. Thus for all $k$, $T_{1k} = \frac{1}{m}$. Putting this all together gives
  $$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{T = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{m} & 1 \\ \vdots & & \ddots \\ \frac{1}{m} &&& 1 \\ \frac{1}{m}}}}.$$

Comment: I really appreciate you going in depth on this. The way the question was worded I would have never figured this out.

Comment: So then when solving for the stationary distribution, would $\pi_1$ = $\pi_1/m + ... + \pi_m/m$, thus giving you $\pi_1 = 1$ when solving for it and $\pi_2, ... , \pi_m = 1$ as well?

Comment: You're welcome, i'm glad you found the explanation useful. The stationary distribution equation is $T \pi = \pi$, and like you say its first component equation is $\pi_1 = \frac{1}{m} \pi_1 + \cdots + \frac{1}{m} \pi_m$, but this doesn't imply $\pi_1 = 1$. Also, remember that in order for $\pi$ to represent a distribution, we must have $\pi_1 + \cdots + \pi_m = 1$. This is no problem, though, since we can scale any nonzero solution of $T \pi = \pi$ to a vector that satisfies this equation.

Comment: Yeah, and I also realized that I typically use the reverse convention so I had to switch it around a bit. I should be able to work it through and really appreciate all you've done!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. If you end up posting a follow-up question about this problem, feel free to add a comment in this thread containing a link, and I'll try to take a look at it.